# Mongoose SchemaTypes Syntax: Array of ObjectIds

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is this

```
blog: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'BlogEntry'}]
```

the same as this

```
blog: {type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'BlogEntry'}
```

or is the second example incorrect?

Comment: I found the second option useful because you can set a custom setter on the schema property with it. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct, but they're not the same. In the first one, the key *blog* is an array of objects. Each object contains two keys: *type* and *ref* where type is a single ObjectId and ref is already define. 
In the second one the key blog is no longer an array but a single object. Now, in this object the key type is an array of ObjectId.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Isn't the second example better then, as the 'ref' key is redundant to be present in every single object?

Comment: You're welcome and that depends of what you want for your application. But yes, with the second example you avoid the redundant.